# Vectorised Hessian calculation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, autodiff

**Problem**

Consider the problem setup

```
x   : A (N, K) tensor that we want to differentiate with respect to.
f(x): A function sending x to a scalar i.e.
          f: R^(N x K) -> R
```

What I want to find is at each observation `x[i,:]` (the size `N` axis) , the gradient (`N x K`) and the Hessian (`N x K x K`).

**Gradients**

Now, the gradients at each observation are easy to find as you simply have to find the gradient of `f` with respect to all `x` values i.e.

```
df/dx[0,0]  ...  df/dx[0,K]
  .                .
  .                .
  .                .
df/dx[N,0]  ...  df/dx[N,K]
```

which can be done simply with

```
tf.gradients(f(x), x)
```

**Hessians**

The problem I now have is with finding the size `(N, K, K)` Hessian tensor. If I use the `tf.hessians` function naively i.e.

```
tf.hessians(f(x), x)
```

this finds (rightly so) a `(N, K, N, K)` tensor of the partial second derivatives, even for `x` values between observations. These are always 0 (in my case), so for large values of `N` this can be very inefficient.

How can I make Tensorflow only find the `N` `(K x K)` Hessian matrices with `j, k` entries `df/(dx[i,j]dx[i,k])`, for observation `i`?

I think there may be a looping solution over the values `0, ..., N-1`, however `N` is also not known to the static graph, it is only defined dynamically for new inputs.

**Dummy Code**

Below is a minimum working example to illustrate the issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

N = 2
K = 3

# Create dummy data.
x_np = np.random.rand(N, K).astype(np.float32)

# Define Tensorflow graph.
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, K), name='x')
f = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x, x), name='f')

grad = tf.gradients(f, x, name='grad')
hess = tf.hessians(f, x, name='hess')

# Run the Tensorflow graph.
sess = tf.Session()

print("\nTensorflow gradient:")
print(sess.run(grad, feed_dict={'x:0': x_np})[0])

print("\nTensorflow Hessian:")
hess_tf = sess.run(hess, feed_dict={'x:0': x_np})[0]
print(hess_tf)

# Show how we can get the Hessian we want from `hess_tf`.
hess_np = np.empty([N, K, K])
for i in range(N):
    hess_np[i, :, :] = hess_tf[i, :, i, :]

print("\nWanted Hessian:")
print(hess_np)
```

Comment: This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310532/tensorflow-compute-hessian-with-respect-to-each-sample.